# Make regex betterer

Tags: javascript, regex

I need an expression that covers two eventualities:

```
www.example.com
knowledge.example.com
```

There are many other possible subdomains so it needs to be specifically either the root domain or the knowledge domain.

I did have a go and this appears to work. But it looks long and unsightly and I wondered if there was a more elegant regex:

```
(www\.)?(knowledge\.)?(example\.com)
```

It's not that long and ugly, I suppose. I'm just curious if I'm approaching it right or if there's a shorter way of writing it.

Comment: what do you want to grab? I thought `()` was a capture group.

Comment: Hi @taesu. This is actually being used within Google Tag Manager environment as a trigger for a script. "Fire the script if user is on either of these two domains". So I don;t need to grab anything perse, GTM will evaluate whether the expression is currently true or not then decide whether to fire the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slightly less ugly, in my opinion:

```
(www|knowledge)\.(example\.com)
```

Sometimes I prefer this:

```
(www|knowledge)[.](example[.]com)
```

Comment: "example.com" does not match this regexp, in difference of original

Comment: The asker says that he wants to match two eventualities, not three. His proposed regex was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Full equivalent of yours regexp:

```
((?:www|knowledge)\.)?(example\.com)
```

Comment: ?: non capturing group? INteresting use of regex, thanks!

Comment: will `example.com` not falsy be true here? since the first group is optional? shouldnt it be `(?:www|knowledge)\.example\.com`?

Comment: @Alex it will be true, because in original regexp its true too )

Comment: "There are many other possible subdomains so it needs to be specifically either the root domain or the knowledge domain." just sayin' ..

Answer (score 1):

Bonus answer,

You can use ***conditionals*** with in your regex pattern, 
Eg. `(?(?!www\.)knowledge|www)(?:\.example\.com)`

Working demo @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hN0mS4/1)

### Edit I

For regex engines that do not support **conditionals**, below is the workaround used to mimic the *if-else* flow:

```
((?(?=positive-regex-statement)then|(?!negavite-regex-statement)then)
((?=www\.)www|(?!www\.)knowledge)(?:\.example\.com)
```

Working demo @ [regex101-javascript-conditionals](https://regex101.com/r/dY6sS6/1)

Comment: Your demo is not working (throws an error in JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the most readable thing in the world. If you want something more clear in its meaning, try this:

```
var domain = 'www.example.com';
var subdomain = domain.replace(/(\w+)\.example\.com/, '$1');
var validSubdomains = ['www', 'knowledge'];
validSubdomains.indexOf(subdomain) != -1;
```